# flutter dart error dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

The following call to the drive function of the AnimationController leads to the error message:

> The argument type 'ColorTween' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animatable'

```
Animation<Color> animation = animationController.drive(ColorTween(begin: Colors.red, end: colors.blue));
```

Yet ColorTween is a Tween<Color?> and Tween<T extends dynamic> is an Animatable<T>.
How can I fix this error? Is the '?' after Color or 'dynamic'
a problem? Explicit casting didn't work either:

> type 'ColorTween' is not a subtype of type 'Animatable<Color>' in type cast

`flutter 2.0.4`
`dart 2.12.2`

Comment: @pskink The assignment was the problem after all. It needs to be Animation<Color?> as ColorTween is a Tween<Color?>. The error message is a bit misleading.

Comment: yes indeed, it is misleading... imho they should be more specific that `null safety` is the problem, not the base type (`Animatiable`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Color` type of the `Animation` in the assignment is missing the '?' as `ColorTween` is a `Tween<Color?>`.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
TweenSequenceItem(
  weight: 1.0,
  tween: ColorTween(
    begin: Colors.black,
    end: Colors.lightBlue,
  ) as Animatable<Color>,
)
```